# WinForm fat client: Architecture decisions: Did I make the wrong ones?

Tags: .net, sql-server, oracle, multi-tier

I have a .NET Winform Click-Once-deployed fat client that talks to three databases, 2 SQL Server databases and a Oracle one.

The first SQL Server database, I will call the Master. I wanted add more tables and columns to the Master database but I was told I would not be given rights to do so, that it was non negotiable. So, I decided to add a new SQL Server database, which I will call the Extensions database to store additional information that I would like to place in the Master.

Since I did not have rights to place the Extension database on the same server as the Master, I created the Extension db on another server and created a db link from the Extension database server to the Master's database server. This allowed me to perform queries that spanned the two databases. I also had a third database, an Oracle one, that I would occasionally connect to.

Because I thought that connecting to the Oracle database requires installing Oracle drivers not likely to be on the end user's PC, I decided to have the WinForm client call a web service and the web service would return the results. For consistency sake and because my gut told me that the database access operations should be performed from one place, I took the same approach when the fat client needed to talk to the SQL Server databases, namely, they went through a web service.

Now I am questioning whether I am taking too big of a performance hit by first having to call the web server and then have the web server call the database instead of opening up a connection on the user's PC in the fat client and connecting directly to the SQL Server databases. Note that the app which I am referring to is an unofficial utility that needs access to these three production databases but is not permitted to actually run in production, so I suspect that the normal high-speed pipes between my development web server and the production database do not apply here.

For best performances, should my Winform app be establishing a connection directly to the SQL Server databases? What are the trade-offs?

Is it still true today that additional drivers are need to connect to an Oracle database or is all of that in the .NET framework now and I could connect directly to even the Oracle database, too, if i wanted?

Also, I found that using the link server is slower than creating two separate db connections and pooling the data together. My best results came when I initiated two a-sync queries and then combined the data together as if it was returned by one query using a db link. However,  this leads to maintenance issues and led me to regret this approach when I needed to modify the SQL do joins across databases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been into developing enterprise applications for couple of years and that has made me think that middle tier(web services in your case) always makes sense and connecting to DB from a UI directly is always a **NO** for me. I don't think you have made a wrong decision. In the long run having a middle tier does make a lot of sense. Also note that, the web-service you have built can be used by different applications.

Comment: Re: "always a NO for me"
My gut tells me that too. But why?

Comment: What will happen if structure of your DB changes or the source from where you fetch the data changes. I mean today you are getting the data from A, B and C dbs. But tomorrow you might get it from just D (whose schema is entirely different from A, B and C). If you are using a middle tier in above scenario, nothing changes for you UI. It keeps doing its work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your performance requirements but a wcf web service is fast. I see nothing wrong in having a middle tier (your web service) for database access. It is also very secure.

Comment: Dunno what a WCF web service is, I guess it is the new generation of web services. But I think that latency of each unnecessary server hop adds up.

Comment: You have built an asmx web service? Change it into a wcf (windows communications framework) web service. Much faster. With wcf you can choose the communication protocol.

Comment: By the way you think that the latency adds up, so you are not sure? You have to measure your performance with a profiling tool to really know the bottlenecks. Don't change your architecture based on guessing.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have configured the Oracle server as a linked server in your SQL server you don't need separate Oracle drivers. You can just use your SQL server as the data source.

Try to create stored procedures to get faster result. If you use SQL management studio you can check the execution plan to optimize your stored procedures (configure indices).

I don't think Webservices are needed in this scenario.

Comment: Connecting through Oracle through a link server in SQL Server would slow my queries down, but I agree that I wouldn't need the web server to perform queries against the Oracle database. 

You said you don't think I need web services in other words, the client should connect directly to the database. Are there any disadvantages? One disadvantage, which doesn't apply in my case, is that my app could be run outside of the co. firewall if the web service were placed outside of it.